# Netty channel closes when exception is thrown

Tags: netty

I have Netty setup in client mode.  I have a simple pipeline with one handler:

```
MyHandler extends Http2ConnectionHandler implements Http2FrameListener
```

If I call `channel.write()` and then throw an exception in the write method intentionally, the channel closes before it hits the `exceptionCaught` method.

What causes a Netty channel to close after an exception is thrown, but before `exceptionCaught` is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually if you would throw an exception in the "write" method it will not be propagated to `exceptionCaught` but it will fail the `ChannelFuture` that is returned by the write method.

When an `Channel` is closed depends on many different factors, like for example the `ChannelFutureListener`s that are used or the `ChannelOutboundHandler` implementations itself. Without more informations its impossible to tell.